# Shift x-axis ticks with scale_x_datetime and geom_col so bars are NOT centered on tick mark

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2, geom-col

I am plotting time series data in half-hour intervals, using geom_col() to show number of birds counted in each interval.  ggplot2 plots each bar *centered* over the x-axis tick mark, but I need each bar to begin to the ***right*** of each tick mark. In other words, I need each bar to span the width of its corresponding half-hour interval.

I have tried the suggested solutions in these posts without luck:

- [Bars starting after x-axis tickmark when using scale_x_datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51987264/bars-starting-after-x-axis-tickmark-when-using-scale-x-datetime)
- [How to force the x-axis tick marks to appear at the end of bar in heatmap graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710463/how-to-force-the-x-axis-tick-marks-to-appear-at-the-end-of-bar-in-heatmap-graph)

Below is example code that reproduces the issue:

````
    ``` r
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  date = c("2019-05-16", "2019-05-16", "2019-05-16", "2019-05-16", "2019-05-16", "2019-05-16", "2019-05-16", "2019-05-16"),
  time = c("16:30:00", "17:00:00", "17:30:00", "18:00:00", "18:30:00", "19:00:00", "19:30:00", "20:00:00"),
  count = c(5, 100, 14, 342, 59, 321, 44, 98),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

datetime_df <- df %>% 
  mutate(time_stamp = paste(date, time) %>% as_datetime())

plot <- ggplot(datetime_df, aes(x = time_stamp, y = count)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = scales::date_breaks("30 mins"), date_labels = "%H:%M",
                                    limits = c(as_datetime("2019-05-16 16:00:00"), 
                                               as_datetime("2019-05-16 20:30:00"))) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), breaks = seq(0, 500, by = 50), limits = c(0,500))
````

<sup>Created on 2020-10-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

[Here is the resulting bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULPQB.png)

Many thanks for any ideas on how to solve this issue!

Comment: By the way, welcome to the site! Great job having your first question be clear, obviously researched, and include a reproducible example!

Comment: Thank you! You made my first experience on the site very rewarding -- drives home the power of providing reproducible examples! Thank you again for your time.

Answer (score 5):

You can mimic this easily by adding 15 minutes to your times:

```
plot <- ggplot(datetime_df, aes(x = time_stamp + minutes(15), y = count)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = scales::date_breaks("30 mins"), date_labels = "%H:%M",
                                    limits = c(as_datetime("2019-05-16 16:00:00"), 
                                               as_datetime("2019-05-16 20:30:00"))) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), breaks = seq(0, 500, by = 50), limits = c(0,500))
plot
```

[image]

To make the ticks line up exactly with the start of the bar, you'll need to set the `width` parameter in `geom_col` to match the number of minutes added. After a little trial and error, this seems to work:

```
half_width_in_min = 13
plot <- ggplot(datetime_df, aes(x = time_stamp + minutes(half_width_in_min ), y = count)) +
  geom_col(width = 60 * 24 * 1.25 * half_width_in_min / 15) +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = scales::date_breaks("30 mins"), date_labels = "%H:%M",
                                    limits = c(as_datetime("2019-05-16 16:00:00"), 
                                               as_datetime("2019-05-16 20:30:00"))) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), breaks = seq(0, 500, by = 50), limits = c(0,500))
plot
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, @GregorThomas !! Your first suggestion to add 15 minutes to the times worked beautifully. I really appreciate your help!